# Is it possible to give each letter stored in an array an id?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to give each letter in an array an Id, currently I have found a way to give each item in an array a Id, but I want to do it for each letter. Is this possible for the current format I have?

```
const words = [
  "triouno stock down", //Sunday
  "the great depression", //Monday
  "stock market crash", //Tuesday
  "ancient egyptian pyramids", //Wednessday
  "nine one one", //Thrusday
  "i am stupid", //Friday
  "share my game", //Saturday
];

words.forEach((item, i) => {
  item.id = i + 1;
});

console.log(words);
```

Comment: You need to use object instead of or array for use your actually code, or you can use array like `array = [ [1, "triouno stock down"], [2, "the great depression"] ... ]`

Comment: Or a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Comment: Would the same letter in another sentence need to have the same id?

Comment: @MarinosAn each item in the array has a day which it gets shown, so the id of the same letters in different sentences can be the same, but the id of the same letters in the given sentence cannot be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer, for a flat array is **No**, it's not possible. But there are several other options.

#### Option #1 - Use a Map

A [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object holds key-value pairs. So you could associate ID with value. In your example:

```js
const words = new Map([
  [1, 'triouno stock down'],
  [2, 'the great depression'],
  [3, 'stock market crash'],
  [4, 'ancient egyptian pyramids'],
]);

// Get single value by ID
console.log(words.get(1));

// Get all values
console.log(...words.values());
```

#### Option #2 - Use an Array of Objects

```js
const words = [
  { id: 1, message: 'triouno stock down' },
  { id: 2, message: 'the great depression' },
  { id: 3, message: 'stock market crash' },
];

// Print all words
words.forEach((word) => {
  console.log(word.message);
});

// Get a specific word (this case, id = 1)
console.log(words.find((word) => word.id === 1).message);
```

#### Option #3 - Use a 2D Array

```js
const words = [
  [1, "triouno stock down"],
  [2, "the great depression"],
  [3, "stock market crash"],
];
```

Comment: Hi Lissy, thanks for the response, each letter gets stored in a span created using js, another option is, could I give each span created an id? the below code does not work, but you get the idea!                                                             
const letterEl = document.createElement("span");
letterEl.forEach((item, i) => {
  item.id = i + 1;
});

console.log(letterEl);

Comment: I think that info should go in your original question, as an edit, because it changes the scope of the answer a bit